# Display different content on page if number from database is met

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

Basically I have a page where I want it to display different content depending on the number which is in the number field in the table in the ms access database.

For example, if the number in the field is equal to or more than 7 then it would display the text label “access granted” if it’s lower than 7, then it would display the text label “access denied”

I’m having trouble on how I would do this in vb. Anyone have an idea on how to do this? Amy help would be approached thanks

Comment: What environment are you in (e.g. WebForms, MVC etc.)? Also, can you please provide a piece of code if you wanted to display the number as is (e.g. 7)? This may help narrow your problem down.

Comment: At @Igor said, you need to post code, not ask to have someone write it for you.  Q: Do you have a connection to the database?  Are you able to query the database?  If you can do the above, then it is a simple If statement.